# Create gradle res value for different api versions

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

Is there any way to create resValue in gradle for specific api version?

I have a `settings.xml` in `values` and `values-v21` folder. Is there any way to override them via gradle `resValue` (I need to have different values in those two api versions)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define:  "api" flavor dimension to group configurations based on API level.

See more on how to define : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html